# Is it legal to use non-whitespace characters betwen field specification? If it's okay, then what is the output we can expect?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(){

int a,b,c;
scanf("%d-%d",&a,&b);
c=a+b;
printf("%d",c);


}
```

What is the output we can expect from this code?

Comment: Also, why not just try it?

Comment: @IngoBürk man scanf.

Comment: Did you try it? input? output? Any surprises?

Comment: @AmirKhasru The code should check the return value from `scanf`. In your case, the return value should be 2. If it's `<=0`, then neither `a` nor `b` is valid. If it's 1, only `a` is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using not whitespace characters in a `scanf` format string is legal.  Those characters are expected to be read and skipped over.  If those characters are not given in the input, `scanf` stops reading at that point.

For example, if your input was `3-4`, the `3` would be stored in `a`, the `-` would match the pattern, and the `4` would be stored in `b` so the output would be 7.

If on the other hand you inputted `4x5`, the 4 would be stored in `a` but the `x` would halt reading of further input because it does not match `-`.  Then `b` would have an undefined value and the result of adding a value to it would also be undefined.

Comment: If scanf stops, then we will find garbage .

Comment: @AmirKhasru Exactly.  Since  `a` and `b` were uninitialized, then a `scanf` failure will leave one or both uninitialized.

Comment: Best buddy. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can separate values with non-whitespace. Here an input of 3--1 will yield 2.
Check the return of scanf. If it fails, the input stream probably needs to be cleaned so subsequent scans can succeed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void){
    int a,b,c;
    int result = 0, clean = 0;
    do {
        printf ( "enter two numbers as n-n\n");
        if ( ( result = scanf("%d-%d",&a,&b)) != 2) {//!=2 is scan failed
            if ( result == EOF) {
                printf ( "could not scan\n");
                return 1;
            }
            while ( ( clean = getchar ( )) != '\n') {
                ;//clean input stream
            }
        }
    } while ( result != 2);//loop on bad input
    c=a+b;
    printf("%d\n",c);
    return 0;
}
```